# HTML Form: How to submit all elements under a div as one array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains multiple divs that contain the exact same thing. Here is an example:

```
<div id="element0">
    textarea(name="front")
    textarea(name="back")
    input(type="radiobutton name="refresh")
</div>
<div id="element1">
    textarea(name="front")
    textarea(name="back")
    input(type="radiobutton name="refresh")
</div>
<div id="element2">
    textarea(name="front")
    textarea(name="back")
    unput(type="radiobutton name="refresh")
</div>
```

When I submit my form to my website, they all appear as arrays of the element names (e.g., `front : { "Something here", "Another here" }, back : { "blah blah", "more blah"` } ) however I want them to be all under a single div array. For example, `element0 : { front : "Something here", back : "blah bah" }, element1: { front : "Another here", back : "more blah" }` Is there an easy why to submit it by  rather than write a script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strait from the jquery docs

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This method `.serializeArray()` can also be called like this if you don't want to wait for the submit event

```
var formArray = $("#formIDHere").serializeArray();
```

Have a look [Here](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for the documentation

---

After your update to the question, I have made you this Javascript function to get the desired result

Call `formToJson(ContainerIDGoesHere)` to have an object returned with the data in.

```
function formToJson(element){
  let finalObject = [];
  $(element).find('div').each(function(){
      let innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
      let formData = {};
      $(this).children().each(function(){
        formData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
      });
      finalObject.push({ "id":innerDivId, "formData":formData});
  });
  return finalObject;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with a working example; https://jsfiddle.net/6z1epu4w/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gave that a try and I am still having trouble getting the output I want. I tried to adjust the input names to  elements[index][front] and use serializeArray but I can't convert it (at least in a one liner). My output looks something like this: `[ [ 'title', '' ],
  [ 'elements[0][front]', '1' ]
  [ 'elements[0][back]', '1' ],
  [ 'elements[0][main]', '1' ] ]`

Comment: Yes thank you. I accidentally submitted the question with the first sentence and you answered way too quickly...